# Is it possible to add buttons to Firefox tabs?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Firefox tabs only have that one button on it to close the tab.  Is it possible to integrate another button, say a "minimize" button that would make the tab narrower/shorter when clicked.  I could not find any specific references in the XUL library that would allow modifications to the browser tab.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you've described you're looking for, but it may guide you somewhere.

I used to create a new 'global' button (like: back/forward, refresh etc.) with [Custom Buttons extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/pl/firefox/addon/custom-buttons/) that once clicked, changed `minWidth` of currently active tab.

The simple code of the button was:

```javascript
gBrowser.mCurrentTab.minWidth *= 1.3;

if(gBrowser.mCurrentTab.minWidth > 300) // back to normality after making it too long
 gBrowser.mCurrentTab.minWidth = 100;
```

It worked until 3.6.*, however it doesn't work with newer Firefox versions, and I've never investigated how to make it compatible. The solution may be trivial though.